# Circular dependency in visual studio .net entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to hold a list of `ClauseComponents` in my class `DeterminateTable`, this is the error that I receive:

> Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.
>
> System.Exception {System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException}

This is the mapper of `DeterminateTable`:

```
public DeterminateTableMapper()
        {
            ToTable("DeterminateTable");

            // Primary key
            HasKey(c => c.DeterminateTableId);

            // Properties
            Property(c => c.DeterminateTableId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            //relations
            HasRequired(d => d.ClauseComponent);
            HasMany(c => c.Results).WithRequired(c => c.DTable).Map(m => m.MapKey("DeterminateTableId")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
```

Probably the code in my projectinitializer is wrong or in the wrong order, First I make all my `ClauseComponent`'s, then I fill the list:

```
List<ClauseComponent> results1 = (new ClauseComponent[]
                {
                    tw10, tw0, tj0,nj200, tk15,tk18, nj400, tk10N, d1, tk3N, tw22, nznw, tw222, d12,
                    tw0Yes, tw0No, tj0Yes,
                    tk15Yes, tk15No, nj400Yes, tk10NYes, tk3NYes,
                    tw22Yes, tw22No, tw222Yes, tw222No, nznwNo,
                    d12Yes, d12No
                }).ToList();
```

After that I assign each component a `DeterminateTable` (which already was made earlier):

```
results1.ForEach(r => r.DTable = detTable1);
```

After that I assign the list to the `DeterminateTable`:

```
 results1.ForEach(r => detTable1.Results.Add(r));
```

These are the properties in DeterminateTable class, I'm trying to hold a ClauseComponent as well as a list of all of them:

```
public int DeterminateTableId { get; set; }
        public virtual ClauseComponent ClauseComponent { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ClauseComponent> Results { get; set; }
```

Class diagram:

[Class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OYO7.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you reposting this question?

Comment: This is another error and trying to do somethng different

Comment: ... but it's the same exception?

Comment: Yes but its another thing that i'm trying to accomplish. So other question...

Comment: Fair enough. Probably the same base-reason for both errors though. =)

Comment: The error in both questions is caused by the same common root.  Can you share the code and a diagram for your entity classes? it appears as though you are trying to map the same table relationships twice with different multiplicities.

Comment: ok, so your statement there shed a bit of light on things... You are trying to hold a single `ClauseComponent`, and at the same time hold a list of all the `ClauseComponents`, including the one that you are referencing singularly?

Comment: Yes thats what i'm trying to do